# jQuery: how can I click in checkbox when id contains some text?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this table:

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td><input id="aaa_1"  type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>1</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="aaa_2"  type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input id="aaa_3"  type="checkbox" /></td>
    <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I want to click in the check where id contains 'aaa_'. After it, I need to know next cell to the side of checkbox.

If I click chckbox one I get the td content 1

I used this code and it is not working:

```
jQuery("[id*=aaa]").one("click", function () {
   alert();
});
```

Comment: Well, an id is should be unique for each DOM element, so you can't name each `td` with `id="aaa_1"`, nor can you call a `td` and an `input` field with the same id.

Comment: make sure you are using your id's only once since they are unique.

Comment: Learn to use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: use `on()` not `one()`

Comment: tds shouldnt have id I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
jQuery("[id*=aaa]").on("click", function () {
   if(this.checked) { // condition if it checked then alert content
       alert(
           $(this).closest('td') // get the closest td element
                  .next('td') // get the next td having your content
                  .text() // get the text/content
       );
   } else {
       alert('Unchecked');
   }
});
```

Comment: it is working but in second click, first click never show the alert.

Comment: Yes I added a condition if the checkbox is checked then it will alert orherwise not you can use else with if. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have duplicate IDs for tds. IDs should be unique.

To check the checkbox:

```
jQuery("[id*='aaa_']").prop('checked', true);
```

to get next cell of checked checkbox cell:

```
nexttd= jQuery("[id*='aaa_']").parent().next();
```

**For Multiple Checkboxes:**

```
jQuery("[id*='aaa_']").each(function(){
    nexttd= jQuery("[id*='aaa_']").parent().next();
});
```